# Remove white space from the start of every new line of a string

Tags: php, regex, string, str-replace

I have a string that comes in in the following format (notice the random number of spaces in between each word and at the beginning of each line):

```
 1 . BritishAirways 15FEB LONDON HONGKONG
```

2 . CathayPacific  01MAR     HONGKONG   SHANGHAI

3 . Qantas   12MAR SINGAPORE SYDNEY

I want the output to be

```
1 . BritishAirways 15FEB LONDON HONGKONG
2 . CathayPacific 01MAR HONGKONG SHANGHAI 
3 . Qantas 12MAR SINGAPORE SYDNEY
```

I've got the below code

```
$flightinfo = preg_replace('/\h+/', ' ', $flightinfo);
$flightinfo = trim($flightinfo);

$flightinfo = str_replace("\r\n\r\n","\r\n",$flightinfo);/* checks and removes double line breaks if they're there.
```

However this gives the below, which is nearly correct however it was white space at the beginning of lines 2 and 3

```
1 . BritishAirways 15FEB LONDON HONGKONG
  2 . CathayPacific 01MAR HONGKONG SHANGHAI 
 3 . Qantas 12MAR SINGAPORE SYDNEY
```

Anyone know how I can remove the white space at the beginning of lines 2 and 3

Answer (score 7):

You may use a single regex replacement to achieve what you need:

```
$flightinfo = preg_replace('~^\h+|\h+$|(\R){2,}|(\s){2,}~m', '$1$2', $flightinfo);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YtrLQY/1).

**Details**

- `^\h+` - any 1 or more horizontal whitespaces at the start of a line (`^` matches a line start due to the `m` modifier)
- `|` - or
- `\h+$` - any 1 or more horizontal whitespaces at the end of a line (`$` matches a line end due to the `m` modifier)
- `|` - or
- `(\R){2,}` - 2 or more line break sequences capturing the last one into Group 1
- `|` - or
- `(\s){2,}` - 2 or more whitespaces capturing the last one into Group 2

The replacement is the replacement backreferences to Group 1 and 2.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/5VbCKC):

```
$re = '/^\h+|\h+$|(\R){2,}|(\s){2,}/m';
$flightinfo = ' 1 . BritishAirways 15FEB LONDON HONGKONG


     2 . CathayPacific  01MAR     HONGKONG   SHANGHAI



  3 . Qantas   12MAR SINGAPORE SYDNEY';
$flightinfo = preg_replace($re, '$1$2', $flightinfo);
echo $flightinfo;
```

Output:

```
1 . BritishAirways 15FEB LONDON HONGKONG
2 . CathayPacific 01MAR HONGKONG SHANGHAI
3 . Qantas 12MAR SINGAPORE SYDNEY
```

Comment: Works good! But how to NOT remove new lines spaces?

Comment: @skywind There is no such a thing as "new line space".

Comment: I mean new extra lines between lines (vertical)

Answer (score 2):

You might just add a further statement to get rid of the trailing whitespace.

```
$flightinfo = preg_replace('/^\s+/m', '', $flightinfo);
```

Answer (score 2):

Generaly you need regex like:

```
"/\s+\s/"
```

With this you detect multi spaces and replace only with one space.

This detect whitespace after new line:

```
"/\n\s+/"
```

This detect whitespace before new line:

```
"/\s+\n/"
```

Double new lines:

```
"\n+"
```

And you can combine this nicely to remove things you don't need.

After all regex  just use `trim()` to clean code.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this:

```
$flightinfo = trim(preg_replace("~\s*\R\s*~", "\n", $flightinfo));
```

It replaces any sequence of white space, including at least one line break (`\R`), with a single line break (`\n`), and trims the result.

Answer (score -1):

To quickly remove *only spaces* from the beginning of each line in `$myString`:

`$myString = preg_replace( "/^ +/m", '', $myString );`

Comment: This does not provide the desired output that is stated in the question.  In other words, this is the correct answer to a different question. https://regex101.com/r/ieWa7r/1  JackFuchs' answer on the other hand IS the correct solution: https://regex101.com/r/ieWa7r/2